# Tf to tflite Conversion issue using graph file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**Tf to tflite Conversion issue

I am running tensorflow version 1.13 and i have provide the graph file path and input arrays and output arrays,input shapes  required for tf lite**

```
input_arrays=['DecodeJpeg/contents']#Input tensor   
output_arrays=['final_result']#output tensor

converter=tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_def_file,input_arrays,output_arrays,input_shapes={'DecodeJpeg/contents':()})

tflite_model = converter.convert()   
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Here converter.convert() throws me below error

```
if not shape or not shape.as_list():
raise ValueError("Provide an input shape for input array "
 "'{0}'.".format(_tensor_name(tensor)))
       shape_list = shape.as_list()
    if None in shape_list[1:]:
```

ValueError: Provide an input shape for input array 'DecodeJpeg/contents'.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to assign input shape for you input array.
Please change `input_shapes={'DecodeJpeg/contents':()}` to `input_shapes={'DecodeJpeg/contents':None}` or according to your input shape like this `input_shapes={'DecodeJpeg/contents':[1,16,16,3]}`.

Comment: My input shape is a scalar. So i just represented it with a tuple

Comment: @sravankumar, have you tried to assign input_shape or just try input_shapes=None.